# VSTS on MS Tier 1 CSP?

Tags: azure, msdn

I work for a Microsoft Tier 1 CSP partner company (Cloud Solution Provider) and I’m trying to figure out if it’s possible to use VSTS (former Visual Studio Online) for our company.

If I understood it correctly, the tier 1 CSP can “create” azure environments for customers. Therefore, the customers could create their own VSTS instances. 
Nevertheless, what about us? Is a VSTS instance available for us as a Tier 1 CSP? Or do we have to book a MSDN Full License to achieve that?

We can link Azure MSP subscriptions to Windows Live ID’s and that allows each user a 130€ credit monthly on Azure components free. However, that only gives us the VSTS “community” edition with five users free because it is not connected to a/the MSDN subscription.

**TL;DR:**

> Can a MS Tier 1 CSP have its own VSTS based on the Tier 1 CSP License?

I hope you guys can give me some insight.

Kind regards

Diogo

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure CSP and VSTS don't play together yet, I don't have a link to back it up thou.